# Laravel Use div value in If

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I am trying to use `div` value in my `If`.
In my JS, I use innerHTML to set `div` value.

```
@if( $day->day_id == '<div id="day">')
```

Comment: So the div doesn't have a value until it's set by javascript?

Comment: yes, I just dont know if the @if can read the value when I use '<div id="day">'

Comment: You won't be able to do this as the blade file will be process on the server and then sent to the browser as simple HTML which is where the javascript will then be processed. The if statement you have will simply be checking if the value of `$day->day_id` is equal to the string '<div id="day">'. If you can explain what you're trying to achieve in more detail and provide the whole blade file there might be an alternative.

Comment: I need to get the <div id="day"> value and use it as variable in the @if

Comment: Yes, but taking a step back what actually is the value of that div. What is the logic to set it? What is it you're trying to show if the value `$day->day_id` does equal what the value would equal?

Comment: If what you're asking for is to change the display of some DOM elements using PHP and depending on user's input. This is doable by javascript not PHP as the server will not be aware of user input until a form is submitted. In short, PHP is not aware of user interactions in the browser. Javascript is your friend their.